# Automating filters using VBA for a pivot table based on the datamodel in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I need to automatically apply a bunch of filters on a pivot table and then store the results. The problem is that the code I have managed to write works fine for a normal Pivot table, but it doesn't work when my Pivot table is based on Excel's datamodel.

I have tried running the macro-recorder to see what changes occur when my pivot table is based on the datamodel, but I'm still unable to make the code work.

''' This is the code that works fine for normal pivot tables

```
  Sub FilterTest1()


  Dim MonthRng As Range, YearRng As Range, OEMRng As Range, cell As Range

  Dim m As Range, y As Range, c As Range


  Set YearRng = Range("E1:I1")

  Set MonthRng = Range("E2:P2")

  Set OEMRng = Range("E3:AE3")


 For Each y In YearRng

  For Each m In MonthRng

    For Each c In OEMRng

         ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("SHIP_DATE (Year)").CurrentPage = y.Value
              ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("SHIP_DATE (Month)").CurrentPage = m.Value
                ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("CUSTOMER_NAME").CurrentPage = c.Value

             Next c

         Next m

     Next y

End Sub
```

''' And this what I'm getting when I'm running the macro-recorder to see how different things look when my pivot table is based on the data model.

```
   Sub test()


       ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
    "[ReadytoAnalyze  2].SHIP_DATE (Year)].[SHIP_DATE (Year)]"). _
         VisibleItemsList = Array("[ReadytoAnalyze  2].[SHIP_DATE  (Year)].&[2014]")

  End Sub
```

''' As you can see, instead of that the value to be hard-coded as 2014, I want to pass a range of several values one by one. And as I mentioned, the first snippet of code works for a normal pivot table but no when  my pivot table is based on the data-model. I feel I'm really close to finding the solution but I would really appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 1):

Can you change the 1st line that sets the Year in your Normal Pivot Macro by :

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("[ReadytoAnalyze  2].SHIP_DATE (Year)].[SHIP_DATE (Year)]"). _
                 VisibleItemsList = Array("[ReadytoAnalyze  2].[SHIP_DATE  (Year)].&[" & y.Value & "]")
```

Nd run the Code ? See which line is showing the error then.

Comment: Yes, it works now. Thank you very much. Appreciate the help! :)

Comment: Cool .... You can change the other lines in the similar way for Month etc.... Also ... accept the answer . :)