How to get pivot items for data model pivot table with VBA
Asked chatgpt to write VBA for me to filter the pivot table with date specified in input box, turned out a lot of errors.
The main issue im facing now is VBA could not get pivot items of the filter field. I have figured out its because pivot table source is connected to data model, so code that works on normal pivot table would not work the same.
I have tried the following code on normal pivot table and it worked, i want it to also work on data model pivot table. Already been researching online for a week but posts are either not relevant or I still cant get my code to work. I would really appreciate any help! And please explain things in simple language if possible as I have 0 experience with VBA.
Sub FilterPivotTableByUserDateWithStringMatch()

    Dim PT As PivotTable
    Dim pivotField As pivotField
    Dim Item As PivotItem
    Dim userDate As String
    Dim dateFound As Boolean
    Dim fieldName As String
    
    ' Specify your Pivot Table
    Set PT = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Client Movements").PivotTables("PivotTable3") ' Adjust to your pivot table name

    ' Specify the exact field name
    fieldName = "New Client Movement" ' Change this to your exact field name

    ' Prompt the user to enter a date
    userDate = InputBox("Enter the date you want to filter (format: mm/dd/yyyy):", "Filter by Date")

    ' Exit if the user cancels the input
    If userDate = "" Then
        MsgBox "No date entered. Exiting filter operation.", vbInformation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Search for the Pivot Field by exact name
    On Error Resume Next
    Set pivotField = PT.PivotFields(fieldName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Check if the pivot field was found
    If pivotField Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Pivot Field '" & fieldName & "' not found in the Pivot Table.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Clear existing filters
    pivotField.ClearAllFilters

    ' Ensure all items are visible before filtering
    For Each Item In pivotField.pivotItems
        Item.Visible = True
    Next Item

    ' Attempt to filter by checking for string match
    dateFound = False
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each Item In pivotField.pivotItems
        ' Compare the item name and user input as strings
        If CStr(Item.Name) = CStr(userDate) Then
            Item.Visible = True
            dateFound = True
        Else
            Item.Visible = False
        End If
    Next Item
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Check if the specified date was found and filtered
    If Not dateFound Then
        MsgBox "The date '" & userDate & "' is not available in the pivot field items.", vbExclamation
        ' Reset all items to visible if the filter date is not found
        For Each Item In pivotField.pivotItems
            Item.Visible = True
        Next Item
    Else
        MsgBox "Pivot Table filtered to date: " & userDate, vbInformation
    End If

End Sub




Thanks for joining Stack Overflow. I suspect that the community is not able to teach how to write and debug VBA code. You may want to start with a tutorial for getting started and then step through your code line by line to see where it is not working as expected.

You might find a clue here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/56713332/7446760
